# Scrolling past certain point does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use a scroll function to run a function once it passes greater than or less than `<a>` tags. First the starting point which is fixed on the page:

```
 <div style="height: 200px">
     <input type="text" id="starting-point" />
 <div>
```

This is setting the starting point at 200px from the top of the page. Then the container behind it could be anything from 1000px to 3000px when scrolling (using the window as scrolling).

```
 <div style="height: 200px;">
     <input type="text" id="starting-point" />
 <div>
 <div style="height: 3000px;">
     <!-- ... content here  -->
     <div style="height: 200px;">
       <a href="">1</a>
     </div>
     <div style="height: 300px;">
       <a href="">2</a>
     </div>
     <div style="height: 240px;">
       <a href="">3</a>
     </div>
     etc...
 </div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is for each `<a>` tag that passes the starting point, to do show something. So when scrolling it starts at 1, once 2 reaches the starting point, something on the page (like a textbox) would switch it from 1 to 2, and so on going down, and then work in reverse going back up. This is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
    var setStart = $('#starting-point').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop(); // starting point
    var getTag = $('a');

    if (setStart >= getTag) { 
        run function here
    }else{
        run function here
    }
    });
});
```

I don't know how to set a variable to when an `<a>` tag passes that starting point to pass it into the function to run what I need. There could be 20 `<a>` tags on the page. Running a for loop I don't think solves the issue.

Comment: `setStart` is an offset and `getTag` is a jQuery element. However, you are trying to compare them. Is that on purpose or did you forget the `.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()` after `var getTag = $('a')` ?

Comment: yeah thats on purpose to set the element

Comment: can you elaborate on that please ?

Comment: setstart is just a variable used as a barometer to where each a tag is passing. The jquery element doesn't necessarily need to be a jquery element, I just used it in this example to have it set in some way to pass it in the if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo on how you could do it.

There could be some other way too.

On load, we get the position of the `#starting-point` and all the anchors which now have the `scroll_target` class.

Then, on scroll, you have to determine the scrolling direction... Because the logic is slightly different going up compared to going down.

Each time it passes a "target" position, the `scroll_target` is decremented/incremented.
So you know which anchor just passed because of the position array.

I made a text array to update the input based on the anchor's text that just passed. It could also be the anchor's value or a data-* attribute.

I left all console logs for you to see what is going on.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var startPoint = $("#starting-point").offset().top;
  console.log(startPoint);
  
  var scrollTargets_pos = [];
  var scrollTargets_text = [];
  
  var scrollingDown = true;
  var lastScroll = 0;
  
  $(".scroll_target").each(function(){
    scrollTargets_pos.push($(this).offset().top);
    scrollTargets_text.push($(this).text());
  });
  console.log(scrollTargets_pos);
  console.log(scrollTargets_text);
  
  var passedIndex = -1;
  
  $(window).on("scroll",function(){
    var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log(scrolled);
    
    // Scroll direction
    scrollingDown = (scrolled > lastScroll);
    lastScroll = scrolled;

    if(scrollingDown){
      // Scrolling down...
      //console.log("down");
      if( scrolled+startPoint > scrollTargets_pos[passedIndex+1] ){
        console.log("======================");
        $("#starting-point").val(scrollTargets_text[passedIndex+1]);
        passedIndex++;
      }
    }else{
      // Scrolling up...
      //console.log("up");
      if( scrolled+startPoint < scrollTargets_pos[passedIndex] ){
        console.log("======================");
        $("#starting-point").val(scrollTargets_text[passedIndex])
        passedIndex--;
      }
    }
  
  });
  
  
});  // End ready
```

```css
.startPointDiv{
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
.content{
  height: 3000px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="startPointDiv">
   <input type="text" id="starting-point" />
</div>

<div class="content">
   <!-- ... content here  -->
   <div style="height: 200px;">
     <a href="" class="scroll_target">1</a>
   </div>
   <div style="height: 300px;">
     <a href="" class="scroll_target">2</a>
   </div>
   <div style="height: 240px;">
     <a href="" class="scroll_target">3</a>
   </div>
   etc...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this

Comment: I did some modifications to make it work, thanks for the help!